# "Apache2 Syntax Error: Cannot load mod_jrun22.so - undefined symbol: ap_log_error"

Tags: apache, ubuntu, coldfusion, trouble-tickets

**Our server is running ubuntu 12.04 with ColdFusion 6.1 using Apache2(2.2.3) webserver connectors
I upgraded the ubuntu to 14.04 and now Apache server stop working with the following error **

```
* Starting web server apache2                                                                                                                                             *
* The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/jrun.load: Cannot load /opt/coldfusionmx/runtime/lib/wsconfig/1/mod_jrun22.so into server: /opt/coldfusionmx/runtime/lib/wsconfig/1/mod_jrun22.so: undefined symbol: ap_log_error
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Apache error Log are as follow

```
  1  [Sun Mar 17 06:38:34 2024] [notice] jrApache[init]  JRun 4.0 (Build 108795) Apache 2.2 module - May  3 2012 09:17:00
     2  [Sun Mar 17 06:38:34 2024] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) JRun/4.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
     3  [Wed Mar 20 16:14:07 2024] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
     4  [Wed Mar 20 16:19:32 2024] [notice] jrApache[init]  JRun 4.0 (Build 108795) Apache 2.2 module - May  3 2012 09:17:00
     5  [Wed Mar 20 16:19:32 2024] [notice] jrApache[init]  JRun 4.0 (Build 108795) Apache 2.2 module - May  3 2012 09:17:00
     6  [Wed Mar 20 16:19:32 2024] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) JRun/4.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
     7  [Wed Mar 20 16:52:37 2024] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
     8  [Wed Mar 20 16:52:38 2024] [notice] jrApache[init]  JRun 4.0 (Build 108795) Apache 2.2 module - May  3 2012 09:17:00
     9  [Wed Mar 20 16:52:38 2024] [notice] jrApache[init]  JRun 4.0 (Build 108795) Apache 2.2 module - May  3 2012 09:17:00
    10  [Wed Mar 20 16:52:38 2024] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) JRun/4.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
    11  [Wed Mar 20 16:54:04 2024] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Steps I did before upgrade

stop ColdFusion
stop apache2

apt-get update
apt-get upgrade

do-release-upgrade

during upgrade get pop up saying about smb point modification I selected the "keep the existing config file for samba points  "

I troubleshoot and check all the files which are causing the problem but no luck
can some one tell me exactly where to look

Answer (score 1):

ColdFusion MX (version 6) reached its end of life around 15 years ago. JRun is long dead. That Apache connector (`mod_jrun22.so`) will not run on the upgraded versions of Ubuntu and Apache. I hope that's a dev server you've upgraded, not a production server. You're stuck on the old operating system and web server versions unless you can also upgrade to the latest version of ColdFusion. If that's a public-facing application, it's a massive security risk to stay on CFMX 6.1.

Alternatively, you can try running your application on https://www.lucee.org/, an open-source CFML application server. Unless you have some `CFX` custom tags or other old school libraries, you should be able to at least test the application pretty quickly.

Comment: Yes I know its' old but , it was created decade ago person who has created this isn't here anymore and left no documentation don't know , it was sitting still for very long but now they needed it , i just joined and I wanted to make this server updated 

let me try and do the cold fusion upgrade and later I will do the ubuntu upgrade
if it won't work I will try your second option 

Thank you

Comment: If this is an internal-use-only application, you could try running it on the existing Ubuntu version but restrict the server to internal network requests only—basically, no public Internet access to the application. That could alleviate security concerns to some degree.